# Using stacks in Java

Tags: java, stack

I'm new to learning java and am having a little difficulty with this. I'm supposed to use a stack to kind of trace genealogy from an imported file. I've read the file and used a stack array to hold my objects. The user enters two names to see if there is a relation. if there is it should say there is a relation. I don't know if I'm going in the right direction with this or not so I was just looking for a little help. I'm not asking for people to code for me, I just want to learn from suggestions. Here is my code so far.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TracingGenealogies 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        File file = new File("genealogy.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String childName;

        int numChildren;
        int numLines;
        int counter = 0;
        String parentName;

        numLines = inputFile.nextInt();

        Stack[] arr = new Stack[numLines];

        while (inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            Stack stack = new Stack();

            stack.push(inputFile.next());

            numChildren = inputFile.nextInt();

            for (int i = 0; i < numChildren; i++)
            {
                stack.push(inputFile.next());
            }

            arr[counter] = stack;
            counter++;
        }

        System.out.println("Enter 2 names to see if they are a descendant.");
        System.out.println("Enter the parent name: ");
        parentName = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter a childs name: ");
        childName = keyboard.nextLine();
```

The file I'm reading from looks like this:

```
10

Al      3   Beth Carol Dino

Beth    1   Pablo

Carol   3   Ben Alex Mary

Dino    0

Pablo   2   Angela Miguel

Ben     0

Alex    0

Mary    0

Angela  0

Miguel  0
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: please provide what the entries in the input file mean. Eg. : what Beth 1 Pablo mean..??

Comment: you haven't implemented the relation logic yet so how can we help you? currently everything seems fine, perhaps running a debugger or printing the contents of your arr data structure to make sure all the data is in your data structure can be your next step

Comment: @akshayapandey it's likely the number of children that person has, so Beth has 1 child named Pablo

Comment: also it seems a hashmap is a better option for you, whjere your could define hashmap as key=child, value=parent and then search through the hashmap till you do not find a key. It would result in tracing miguel as ...miguel(key)->Pablo(parent)->..similarly pablo(key)-> beth(parent)..beth(key)->AI(parent)

Comment: @akshaya pandey The first name on each line is the parent followed by how many children they have and the childrens names.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz I ran through a debugger and checked my arr data structure. Everything is filled properly. I'm having trouble understanding how I should figure out how to pull a relation out of my structure or if there may be an easier way than what I'm doing right now.

Comment: @akshaya pandey I will try a hasmap. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: do you have to use a stack? or can you use any data structure you want? you can search for the relation using your current data structure of an array of stacks

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz I have to use a stack so I can't use a hashmap. This is homework. That's why I'm just looking for suggestions from others.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to go through your data structure to find a child for a particular parent. In order to find the relationship you have to understand some characteristics about your data. First is to identify a parent versus child, a parent has a stack size greater than 1. If the stack has a size of 1 then you know you have a child. Therefore you need to search all the parents and ignore the children stacks. Next is to simply loop the stack until you find the child's name or you don't find it.

Try this

```
    //loop the array of stacks
    for(int index = 0; index < arr.length; index++)
    {
        Stack curStack = arr[index];
        boolean foundChild = false;
        //a stack with a size > 1 means we have a parent and then we check if it's the parent we want
        if(curStack != null && curStack.size() > 1 && curStack.peek().equals(parentName))
        {
            curStack.pop(); //remove the parents name from the stack
            //search the parent stack for the child's name
            while(!(foundChild = curStack.peek().equals(childName)) && curStack.size() > 0)
            {
                curStack.pop(); //remove the name
            }
        }

        if(foundChild)
        {
            System.out.println(parentName + " has the child named " + childName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That makes sense and I understand what you're doing here. I was definitely overthinking this because that is simple code. Thank you for the lesson!

Comment: your code I find only tells if the two people are in direct parent and child relationship. The assignment is to find if the younger is a descendant of the older

Comment: there are no instructions on this question and so i simply provided a "method" to solve the following question, does child X belong to parent Y. That's all. it does not find all the children of parent Y because that was not what was asked. @ıllıllıкιмσтσıllıllı